# Use Regex in Javascript to return an array of words

Tags: javascript, regex

Try though I may, can't figure out how to use regex in javascript to get an array of words (assuming all words are capitalized). For example:

Given this: NowIsAGoodTime

How can you use regex to get: ['Now','Is','A','Good','Time']

Thanks Very Much!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
'NowIsAGoodTime'.match(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g)
```

`[A-Z]`, `[a-z]` and `[0-9]` are character sets defined as ranges. They could be `[b-xï]`, for instance (from "b" to "x" plus "ï").

[`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) always returns an array or `null` if no match at all.

Finally, the `g` regexp flag stands for "global match". It means, it will try to match the same pattern on subsequent string parts. By default (with no `g` flag), it will be satisfied with the first match.

With a globally matching regexp, `match` returns an array of matching substrings.

With single match regexps, it would return the substring matched to the whole pattern, followed by the pattern groups matches. E. g.:

```
'Hello'.match(/el(lo)/) // [ 'ello', 'lo' ]
```

[See more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) on `Regexp`.

Comment: Perfect!! This works great!! Might I ask as a follow on, how, if possible, can I include 4 digit numbers like words to the result. For example 2011NowIsAGoodTime -> ['2011','Now','Is','A','Good','Time']. I can easily do this without regex (but of course Regex is more elegant :-) ) Thanks again for the solution to the original question; I understand it and it works perfectly. BTW, for me case, the optional 4 digit number, if present, will always be at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Your welcome, and thanks to @Marcus, too. `/([0-9]{4}|[A-Z][a-z]*)/g` should include 4-digit numbers.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Wow. This is great. Let me try to explain how it works for myself and others who might need an explanation. Please correct me if I'm wrong: Optionally match 4 digits or words that begin with A-Z followed by any number of a-z; the * only pertains to the [a-z]. Enclosing the whole expression in () is what causes the array to be returned, and the g at the end makes it work, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Parens were actually redundant! I've updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This regex will break it up in desired parts:

```
([A-Z][a-z]*)
```